# Have kile detect whether to use PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, kile

I use plain LaTeX for research papers (which don't run without error in XeLaTeX) and XeLaTeX for presentations (which use fontspec).
I am working with Kile and have a shortcut (Alt+2) for QuickBuild with PDFLaTeX which I am very accustomed to. Now I could easily choose a different Shortcut for a QuickBuild with XeLaTeX. However, I always accidentally push Alt+2 creating errors, which is a bit annoying.

Is there any way to have Kile recognize automatically which command should be used to build the current file?
I'm fine with putting some document type declaration like "% use xelatex" at the beginning of the document if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Linux or Mac, you can use the following script as "compiler" for Kile:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
read -r line < "$filename"
directive=${line:0:5}
latex=${line:6}
if [ "$directive" == "% use" ]; then
    eval "$latex" "$filename"
else
    eval pdflatex "$filename"
fi
```

It checks if the first line of the input file contains the `% use [compiler]` directive and executes it if found, if not it defaults to `pdflatex`.

Note: this does not copy other command-line arguments (such as `--shell-escape`), and probably has other problems I didn't think of.